# Change http://i.example.com/img.jpg to http://www.example.com/show/i/img.jpg

Tags: javascript, regex

Can you help me convert the link:

```
http://i.example.com/pbabp.jpg
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/show/i/pbabp.jpg
```

using regex in JavaScript?

Comment: Without more examples, the following would be a "solution": `function(s){ return 'http://www.domain.com/show/i/pbabp.jpg'; }`

Comment: I understand the need for clarification on most questions, and this question was just vague enough to justify your snark comment...But really? I understood it, as did @Lekensteyn, it's not that difficult of a concept to grasp, but thanks for your contribution

Comment: I actually just wanted another example so that I could write a real answer.  It's not clear to me what is supposed to change, or what should be accepted (files, directories, is `i` a single subdomain or may it be nested, etc).

Comment: (That is to say, snarkiness wasn't intended).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick the part before `.example.com` and put it after it together with `/show/`:

```
input.replace(/^(http:\/\/)(.+?)(\.example\.com)/i, "$1www$3/show/$2");
```

Replace `http` by `https?` if you need to match both `http://...` and `https://...`.